# Oracle TimesTen vs Oracle database in-memory

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, in-memory-database, timesten

Oracle has recently announced its latest [Oracle database in-memory](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/features/database-in-memory-option/index.html) feature in 12c.

Oracle already had an in-memory database TimesTen and now I was wondering as to what the the differences between these two beasts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a massive difference. TimesTen is an dedicated in-memory database.

Oracle in-memory is just an added optional extra for Oracle 12c that lets you mark data, given certain indexing rules (you drop them), as in-memory. Oracle then caches the data in memory in both a row and columnar fashion, enabling fast retrieval for both OLTP and reporting workloads. It requires no code changes for existing Oracle-based applications - completely transparent & can offer significant performance improvements.

Comment: This question may sound very trivial, as I am not a db geek just a curious software dev. Thanks alot.